# Angular service duplicating data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework and I have 2 views, one for all my stores and another for the store details. Both are reading data from a service.
My problem is that when I click in one store and go back, all the stores are appending again.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rkxX05tmnWb4wDYcA6mT?p=preview) with my code

Thanks!

---

Edit:

In the answers I saw that one solution is add the array inside my get function, this stops my duplicate data, but what if I want to read an object of my array. Now I have the array inside the get function like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga8RVpwOvTnl4qkRVaWT?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your stores array is only instantiated once, but you were pushing into it every time you called the getStores method.

check out this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/J6wnDEYDLPT5tsG1VYey?p=preview

Comment: Great, this stops my duplicate data. But what if I want to read an object of my array. Now I have the array inside the get function. Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ga8RVpwOvTnl4qkRVaWT?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Services/factories in angular are singletons, so when you have the code below, you are initializing the stores array once, per app, but every time you call `get` you are adding to it.

```
var stores = [];

return {
    get: function () {
        stores.push(
```

To resolve this, you should define the stores array inside the get function, like so:

```
return {
    get: function(){
        var stores = [];
        stores.push(...
```

In order to preserve your array, declare the array outside of the get function, but clear the array before pushing additional items to the array.

```
var stores =[]; //declared outside get function so it will persist throughout the service
return {
    get: function(){
        stores = []; //reset upon get so data won't be duplicated
        stores.push(...
```